# Spring MVC Controller and logging post data with logback

Tags: spring-mvc, logging, logback

What is the best way to log post data from a controller?  I cant find any good example using logback or another logging framework.  I cant debug a request because I cant see the post data and I dont want to add an interceptor.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/notification")
    @ResponseBody
    public void notification(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just iterated the parameters and spit them out.

```
String getCaseInsensitiveParameter(HttpServletRequest request, String parameter){
        Map params = request.getParameterMap();
            Iterator i = params.keySet().iterator();
            while ( i.hasNext() )
              {
                String key = (String) i.next();
                String value = ((String[]) params.get( key ))[ 0 ];
                if (parameter.equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
                    return value;
                }
              }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no built-in way to do this.

I would write a custom `Filter` that wraps the `HttpServletRequest` with a `HttpServletRequestWrapper` that reads the request `InputStream` into a `BufferInputStream` and log out its content as a `String` when a `POST`(or other) method is received.

Note that you wouldn't want to log that content if it's just binary.